# Read textfile in VHDL testbench

Tags: vhdl

I have a file `source.txt`, it looks like this:

```
00660066006700670067006800680069006B006D006E
00660066006700670067006800680069006B006D006E
00660066006700670067006800680069006B006D006E
00660066006700670067006800680069006B006D006E
00660066006700670067006800680069006B006D006E
0065006500660067006700690069006A006B006C006E
00650065006600670067006700680069006A006C006D
00650065006600670067006600660068006A006B006D
006500650066006700670065006600670069006B006D
00650065006600670067006600670068006A006C006D
0065006500660067006700690069006A006B006C006E
*
```

After each line there is the hidden newline character '\n'.
The asterix '*' is my visible end-of-file character.

How do I write a testbench in VHDL that does the following:

- read file
- store one line in a vector
- write that vector in a new `target.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using VHDL-2008, and showing the `std_logic_vector` underway, the code can be:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use std.textio.all;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture syn of tb is
begin
  process is
    variable line_v : line;
    file read_file : text;
    file write_file : text;
    variable slv_v : std_logic_vector(44 * 4 - 1 downto 0);
  begin
    file_open(read_file, "source.txt", read_mode);
    file_open(write_file, "target.txt", write_mode);
    while not endfile(read_file) loop
      readline(read_file, line_v);
      hread(line_v, slv_v);
      report "slv_v: " & to_hstring(slv_v);
      hwrite(line_v, slv_v);
      writeline(write_file, line_v);
    end loop;
    file_close(read_file);
    file_close(write_file);
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: For IEEE compatibility you should have used `use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; use ieee std.textio.all;` and analyzed Morten's code as VHDL -2008. Morten used `ieee.numeric_std.all;` where he should have used `use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;`. He also left the entity declaration out. If it didn't work perhaps you were a bit premature in accepting the answer?

Comment: Making those changes and Morten's code runs on your lines of source.txt producing target.txt. You could also note you could eliminate slv_v using readline  and writeline line_v instead of hread and hwrite and eliminating the report statement, or make slv_v a signal so it's useful outside the process (a VHDL file copy doesn't seem particularly useful).

Comment: Guess JohannesKlaus merged relevant parts into own code, and that the rewrite of target was requested for use as template to make other data.  For other to benefit code is updated to be self contained.